# Impossible to copy image from remote server when the image name has whitespaces

Tags: php, copy, remote-server

I am trying to copy image from remote server, but the image name has whitespaces and the file that is created from copy() function is invalid and can not be opened. My code is:

```
$url     = 'http://www.bgelectronics.eu/image/cache/data/cantell kabeli /14222-228x228.jpg';

$newfile = servImagesDir.'products/small/awa.jpg';
if (!copy($url, $newfile)){echo "failed to copy";}
```

No errors and as I said above there is a copied file but invalid. Same time the image is good
Please help to solve this, Thanks

Comment: Try to paste in second (empty) line:   $url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);

Comment: I tryed with rawurlencode which does the same but no success..

Comment: Ops, it works man, obviously it is not the same ! Please answer as answer so I can accept it ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to paste in second (empty) line:

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url);
```

---

urlencode and rawurlencode also encode '/' (slashes). They change your URL to:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bgelectronics.eu%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fdata%2Fcantell%20kabeli%20%2F14222-228x228.jpg